# Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I'm getting this error while trying to run:

```
docker-compose run app python manage.py migrate
```

with Django.

this is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  database: { }

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/dev/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.dev/.app
      - ./.envs/.dev/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  postgres:
    image: "postgres:13.1"
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.dev/.postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. PostgreSQL is running correctly and all the settings are appropiately configured.

This is the full traceback error:.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've searched for multiple answers and tried multiple solutions but they are not working.

They have asked me to put the .postgres note so here it is:

```
POSTGRES_USER=app
POSTGRES_DB=app
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<set_me>
```

And also the database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": 'DjangoCRM',
        "USER": 'postgres',
        "PASSWORD": 'xxxx',
        "HOST": 'localhost',
        "PORT": '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste `./.envs/.dev/.postgres`, please?

Comment: and the database related `settings.py` part?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to connect to postgres on localhost, but you should be using the container name `postgres`. `localhost` is the *container's* localhost, not your machine's localhost

Comment: Can you check whether the postgresql is running on port 5432? `service postgresql status`, `sudo netstat -nl | grep postgres`

Comment: Yes, already edited with .postgres and settings. Which is the container name ```postgres```?

Comment: The service name `postgres` in the `docker-compose.yml` file is usable as a host name; as @C.Nivs points out, "localhost" in Docker usually means "this container".  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details.